# Sklean learning_curve() ? How does it return a train score?

Tags: cross-validation, scikit-learn

So learning_curve() returns train AND test scores... What does it mean by train score?

I've passed in a 10 fold stratified k fold and the way I understand it you fit on the train and log the score on the test data set.

With this in mind , I understand the test score but HOW is it creating a TRAIN score?

the DOCSTRING says:

> train_scoresarray, shape (n_ticks, n_cv_folds) Scores on training
>   sets.
>
> test_scoresarray, shape (n_ticks, n_cv_folds) Scores on test set.

Answer (score 0):

As described [in the documentation](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.learning_curve.html), it computes:

> Determines cross-validated training and test scores for different
>   training set sizes.

so it trains the model on different sample sizes, then computes and records the scores on train and test set.

Comment: yes but how can you get a score on the training set. I thought that was just for training?

Comment: @LewisMorris Same as on test set: you plug-in the training data, make predictions and compare to the labels on the training set to compute the metric. The procedure is the same no matter what data you plug-in.

Comment: You train and predict on the same data? Is that what you are saying? I.e est.fit(X_train,y_train)        est.predict(X_train) ???

Comment: @LewisMorris yes, this is what we call "training error".

Comment: ok great that helps me. Thank you so much